# How can I achieve this custom slider design in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am developing a app where I need this design. Can you tell me how can I achieve this in flutter?

[image of the ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGmTF.png)

I tried with circular slider. But can not achieve the ui.

Comment: can you explain what should happen if you were to slide it?

Comment: Try to use [custom_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/custom_slider) or [sleek_circular_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider) package